# Is it possible to deploy existing android app in MC18 scanner using EMDK?

Tags: android, motorola-emdk

My app is equipped with a barcode scanner. I want to deploy same app in MC18 too so. And I want app to use MC18's own scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Zebra Technologies has made available a custom SDK to control MC18's barcode scanner.

You can find more information on the [Zebra developer website](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/android/emdk).
Here you can find the download packages, tutorials, sample and the reference guide.

You cannot use on the MC18 other Barcode library (like ZXing) to control the hardware barcode scanner because these consumer library normally are built to use the device camera.